# How to redirect Flask user to a 'successful completed' page after cloud function has been called?

Tags: flask, google-cloud-functions

I am working on a flask web app to be hosted on Google App Engine.

In the app a user will hit a button to request the app to run a report.

Flask will then send an HTTP API request with accompanying arguments to Cloud Functions.

Cloud Functions will then process the request and then run a Python function that will do all the necessary stuff to generate the report (query the database, build the excel, populate it etc…) and then email the report to the user.

Afterwards I would like to redirect the user to a "task successfully completed" page in the web app.

How can this be done? i guess the cloud function could post a request back to flask which then redirects to successfully completed page. But at that point, how would Flask know which user to redirect?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using flask login then if the user is logged in then you can know which user the flask app should show the credentials for.

or you could generate a token for user which the web app will send to the "Cloud Function" and when the task is completed, it will send a API request back to flask with the token. then you can use that determine which user

Comment: thanks, does flask login generate a token automatically then? where does flask login store the token?

Comment: No you would have to create methods for that

Comment: If you use flask login no need for token if the user is logged in

Comment: Thank you. I’m still confused about what’s going on behind the scenes in Flask Login though. There could be several users logged into the app at the same time, how does Flask Login know which user session to attribute the request to and consequently implement the redirect to the ‘task completed’ page?

Comment: Flask uses session to track which user has logged in. So each user's browser has a session variable. Flask login retrieves it and such we can see if the user has logged in or not. If you are still confused we extend the discussion. Also take a look at the docs for flaks Login